# How do I define callback in Stencil Handlebars

Tags: bigcommerce

[Some](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/handlebars-syntax-and-helpers/handlebars-helpers-reference/array-helpers/standard-array-helpers#handlebars_some) is a block helper that returns the block if the callback returns true for some value in the given array.

```
{{#some array isString}}
  Render me if the array has a string.
{{else}}
  Render me if it doesn't.
{{/some}}
//=> 'Render me if the array has a string.'
```

How do I define the callback in a a stencil theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Stencil theme, the callback function would need to be a helper that exists in Stencil, rather than a function you define. We'll update the docs to note that the callback must be a pre-existing helper.

Comment: include which callback functions are available if possible.

Comment: I think the main thing would be that the helper returns a boolean and can be iterated over each array item. We'll get something more specific into the docs!